# Dynamically copy rows of data from one Excel file to another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I have large amounts of data for different serial numbers spread across many files that I would like to dynamically copy into a template using a reference cell value and the INDIRECT() function. I would like to do this without using VBA macros.

For example, in the template: Cell A1: `SN016`. Cell A2: `=INDIRECT("C:\Users\Johannes\TestData\"&A1&"\[data.xlsx]Sheet1!A2")`

The idea is to change A1 to the corresponding file location of the data and update the entire range of data in the template. I'm getting a #REF! result though when I try this. It would also be nice if I could drag the copy-formula box and have `Sheet1!A2` become `Sheet1!A3`, `Sheet1!A4`, `Sheet1!B2`, etc. That might be asking for too much though!

Comment: Do you need to use VBA? You can use Power Query instead of VBA. It will be much more easier i think. DId you consider this?

Comment: I would prefer to NOT use VBA. I haven't heard of Power Query but I will look into it.

Comment: According to the documentation for INDIRECT: If ref_text refers to another workbook (an external reference), the other workbook must be open. If the source workbook is not open, INDIRECT returns the #REF! error value

Comment: Okay, @TomSharpe is correct, unfortunately. To further explain, the other workbook must be open AND you cannot include any part of its file location as part of the INDIRECT function, as I tried to do. I was able to get it to work by only including the `[data.xlsx]` (without the C:\ location) in the formula. This completely negates the benefit of what I was trying to do, so I guess there just isn't a formula solution.

Comment: It isn't quite the end of the story, there is the INDIRECT.EXT function from the MOREFUNC add-on. There is some advice on using it here http://www.ashishmathur.com/tag/morefunc/ but it only works up to Excel 2010 (32-bit). There's also the Pull function with an update here http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/Q_28466130.html